Error of openpyxl v 3.1 or newer needed but openpyxl 3.1 is installed
I am fairly new to Python and started receiving a new error on a workbook that I have consistently executed in the past.
I keep receiving the following error:
ImportError: Pandas requires version '3.1.0' or newer of 'openpyxl' (version '3.0.10' currently installed).

However, when I execute pip list it shows me openpyxl 3.1 is installed.
To use Python I just open the command prompt and type Jupyter Lab, so I don't believe I'm using Anaconda or anything like that.
Any info on how I can fix this error?
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling openpyxl, but received the same error. Also started a new notebook and same thing. I know the code is correct because I have used this many times before.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify how you installed openpyxl.  Make sure you're using the same pip as the version of Python you're using with Jupyter, as in the path of pip is the same as the path of Python you're using.

Run which python or where python in your command prompt to confirm the Python path that Jupyter Lab is using.
Run pip show openpyxl and pip show pandas to verify the versions and installation paths. This will help confirm that your Jupyter Lab session uses the same environment where openpyxl 3.1.0 is installed

and then Since you're using the command prompt, run:
bash
Copy code
pip install --upgrade openpyxl
in the same command prompt where you start Jupyter Lab. This should upgrade openpyxl in the environment Jupyter uses. Restart Jupyter Lab and Kernel

I was able to fix this issue by running the following code in a cell in Jupyter Lab notebook itself.
pip install openpyxl --upgrade


Ideally when running such installs in the notebook you can make it explicit to use the magic install mode with %pip install openpyxl --upgrade. Because automagics are usually on, it will run the magic version behind the scenes for you, but best to be clear for helping others that they want the magic version. See more about the modern %pip commands for running inside a running notebook here to target the pip actions actual environment where the kernel is running.
